unable to change flutter web default browser to brave
for some reason my flutter app is not opening up with brave anymore (stopped working 5 minutes ago), its opening with safari now.
im using vs code and a Mac.
this is my launch json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter Web",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": [
                "-d",
                "web-server",
                "--web-port=8080",
                "--web-browser-flag=--browser-path=/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

these are the commands I tried using chatgpt/claude:
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % flutter config
Configure Flutter settings.

To remove a setting, configure it to an empty string.

The Flutter tool anonymously reports feature usage statistics and basic crash reports to help improve Flutter tools over time. See Google's privacy
policy: https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/

Global options:
-h, --help                  Print this usage information.
-v, --verbose               Noisy logging, including all shell commands executed.
                            If used with "--help", shows hidden options. If used with "flutter doctor", shows additional diagnostic information.
                            (Use "-vv" to force verbose logging in those cases.)
-d, --device-id             Target device id or name (prefixes allowed).
    --version               Reports the version of this tool.
    --enable-analytics      Enable telemetry reporting each time a flutter or dart command runs.
    --disable-analytics     Disable telemetry reporting each time a flutter or dart command runs, until it is re-enabled.
    --suppress-analytics    Suppress analytics reporting for the current CLI invocation.

Usage: flutter config [arguments]
-h, --help                                 Print this usage information.
    --list                                 List all settings and their current values.
    --clear-ios-signing-cert               Clear the saved development certificate choice used to sign apps for iOS device deployment.
    --android-sdk                          The Android SDK directory.
    --android-studio-dir                   The Android Studio installation directory. If unset, flutter will search for valid installations at
                                           well-known locations.
    --jdk-dir                              The Java Development Kit (JDK) installation directory. If unset, flutter will search for one in the
                                           following order:
                                           1) the JDK bundled with the latest installation of Android Studio,
                                           2) the JDK found at the directory found in the JAVA_HOME environment variable, and
                                           3) the directory containing the java binary found in the user's path.
    --build-dir=<out/>                     The relative path to override a projects build directory.
    --[no-]enable-web                      Enable or disable Flutter for web.
    --[no-]enable-linux-desktop            Enable or disable support for desktop on Linux.
    --[no-]enable-macos-desktop            Enable or disable support for desktop on macOS.
    --[no-]enable-windows-desktop          Enable or disable support for desktop on Windows.
    --[no-]enable-android                  Enable or disable Flutter for Android.
    --[no-]enable-ios                      Enable or disable Flutter for iOS.
    --[no-]enable-fuchsia                  Enable or disable Flutter for Fuchsia.
                                           This setting applies only to the master channel.
    --[no-]enable-custom-devices           Enable or disable early support for custom device types.
    --[no-]cli-animations                  Enable or disable animations in the command line interface.
    --[no-]enable-native-assets            Enable or disable native assets compilation and bundling.
                                           This setting applies only to the master channel.
    --[no-]enable-flutter-preview          Enable or disable Flutter preview prebuilt device.
                                           This setting applies only to the master and beta channels.
    --[no-]enable-swift-package-manager    Enable or disable support for Swift Package Manager for iOS and macOS.
                                           This setting applies only to the master channel.
    --clear-features                       Remove all configured features and restore them to the default values.

Run "flutter help" to see global options.

Analytics reporting is currently enabled.
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % 
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % 
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % 
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % flutter config --clear-web-browser-path
Could not find an option named "clear-web-browser-path".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % flutter config --web-browser-path="/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser"
Could not find an option named "web-browser-path".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % 
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % 
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % ls -l "/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser"
-rwxr-xr-x@ 2 juan  admin  207792 Dec 19 02:03 /Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % 
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % 
(base) juan@192 flutter_dummy % flutter doctor 
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 14.3.1 23D60 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.2.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.96.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources


I found these stackoverflows but I think they are outdated:
Change default web browser in Visual Studio
How to change Flutter DevTools default browser?
this issue happens randomly from time to time but I am unable to fix the issue this time.
any advice is welcomed
